# Can we use the get, add, push, and pop options for Characters on a double ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, get, push, addition

My main question is that I was trying to use Characters and get the value of a character. I was working on a Eulerian method and I was trying to get the next point which was a character, but it wouldn't let me do it for Characters. I was only allowed to do it with Integers. It won't also let me add onto the double ArrayList, which begs the question if that was allowed.

Is it possible to push, pop, get, and add elements that are Characters?

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> adjacents;

void addEdge(char x, char y)
    {
        adjacents.get((Character)x).add(y);
    }
```

I know this works when I use Integers, but I don't understand why not with Characters.

This is coded in Java by the way.

Answer:

After posting this, I got my question answered that we can't use characters and call the functions get, add, remove, etc for an array of characters. I had not known that before, which was why my original question was confusing to many. Let me know if you can do it, because from my understanding right now, I don't think we can.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. The code that you have posted doesn't do that

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes with [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) `get(int index)`.If you pass it an int, you get what you see, but if you pass it a `char` it will be interpreted as the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) value while being [implicitly converted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) to int.

Say you call it for the character "0", implicit conversion gives you a call with ascii/int `get(48)`, which might not exist in the list.

One way to handle it would be to take a `Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>`, that way your code would work as expected.

But actually from your comment it seems like you might be searching for something like this:

```
class Edge{
    public final char from;
    public final char to;

    Edge(char from, char to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
}

List<Edge> adjacents...
```

Comment: Well my main question was if we can add, pop, and push characters. I guess my answer is that it's not.

Comment: @Adan Vivero it was the answer to "I know this works when I use Integers, but I don't understand why not with Characters". You can add and get, but for pushing and popping you need a Stack